# Displaying a vertical sublist beside its parent

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to display a sub-list beside it's parent using only css and no fixed width?

I'm trying to implement a navigation menu in css.  I managed to display the first submenu under it's parent.
But when it come to the submenu of the submenu, I only manged to put it beside it's parent with a fixed offset. But since the offset can differ depending on the width of the parent, and the width of the parent change depending of the browser used, that solution does not work.

here is my css

```
.main-nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-centered {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:10;
}

.nav-main-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color:#91a056;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:25px
}

.nav-main-menu li { 
    display: inline; 
    text-align: center;    
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.nav-main-menu li a img {
    padding-bottom:0px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #91a056;
}

.nav-main-menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #bbc888;
}

.nav-main-menu li li a:hover, .nav-main-menu li li span:hover, .nav-main-menu li li span:hover {
    background-color: #bbc888;
}

.nav-main-menu li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    float:left;
}

.nav-main-menu li li, .nav-main-menu li li li {
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
    width:100%;
    border: 3px ridge #91a056;
}

.nav-main-menu li ul, .nav-main-menu li li ul, .nav-main-menu li:hover li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}

.nav-main-menu li li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    top:0px;
    left:176px; /* I want to get rid of this fixed offset */
}

.nav-main-menu li li li a, .nav-main-menu li li a, .nav-main-menu li li span {
    display:block;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size:100%;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 0 1em;
    background-color: #91a056;
}

.nav-main-menu li li a span{
    padding: 0;
}

.nav-main-menu li a {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    font-size:120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 1em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #91a056;
}
```

I want to get rid of the `.nav-main-menu li li:hover ul` left offset.

And here is the revelant part of my html code

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="main-nav">
<div class="nav-centered">
<ul class="nav-main-menu">
    <li><a href="/" ><span>Acceuil</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle" ><span>Regles de jeu</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Les personnages</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle/commencer" ><span>Se creer un personnage</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle/race" ><span>Les Races</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle/alignement" ><span>Les Alignements</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle/entrainement" ><span>Les Entrainements</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle/conpetence" ><span>Les Competences</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle/handicape" ><span>Les Handicapes</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle/dieu" ><span>Les Dieux</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle/doamine" ><span>Les Domaines</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle/sort" ><span>Les Sorts</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle/profile" ><span>Les Profiles</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle/terrictoire" ><span>Les Terrictoires</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle/prestige" ><span>Les Prestiges</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>Les reglements</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle/combat" ><span>Les Combats</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle/etatAlterer" ><span>Les Etats Alteres</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>L'univers</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle/seigneurie" ><span>Les Seigneuries</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/?_=/page/regle/groupe" ><span>Les Groupes</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-login"><a href="/?_=/login" ><span>Inconnue</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/?_=/login" ><span>Se connecter</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/?_=/page/info" ><span>Qui sommes-nous?</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/?_=/forum" ><span>Forum</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" ><img alt="Page facebook" src="/img/icon-facebook.gif" style="max-width:19.0px;max-height:19.0px;" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are positioning the submenu absolutely, it is not possible to allow it to grow and position the second submenu next to a fluctuating width parent submenu, at least not without JS.

In my experience, generally you would most likely want a fixed width submenu and not be at the mercy of content, because if the content is quite long, this will not look good in the design, at least 99% of the time. 
So I would suggest you constrain the submenu's maximum width and with a bit of planning you can allow for larger content and if long content is unavoidable simply allow it to drop on to two lines.

Also I understand this is probably just example CSS for asking the question, but your CSS styles are not very well laid out and do not cascade very well, this can make advanced CSS styling hard and time-consuming. Try to avoid using long, unclear and complex selectors, the beauty of CSS is being able to easily cascade styles. Smaller concise selectors also help performance.

Using a class you can reduce

```
.nav-main-menu li li li {}
```

to

```
.submenu ul li{}
```

I realise this is not exactly the answer you were probably looking for but I have created a quick basic fiddle with styles to style your submenu's HTML with my suggestions. I have added a class of `.submenu` to all li's that contain submenu's, including secondary submenu's.

http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/xRyMW/

hope this helps

Comment: I was hopping to set different with to different submenu, since a single fixed width for all submenu will make some appear as empty.

Comment: And I have to note your styling suggestion is a lot cleaner than my style. thx

Comment: No problem. If you wanted different size submenu's you could always set different submenus to have different widths by adding further classes to them. This way you still have control but have flexibility too, as a quick example I have a further fiddle with `.smaller` and `.larger` classes, this is then placed on submenu's to control width of submenus and the left position of child submenu's: http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/xRyMW/4/ (you may need to tweek slightly depending on your mixture of larger and smaller submenu's)